# De duplication of hashes and arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, sorting, hash

I have an array of hashes lets say offers = {offer1,...,offer6}. Each offer is a hash. 
Each offer has various keys one of which is a price hash:
offer1 = {..., :price => {:amount => 400, :amount2 => 300, :currency => "INR",...}

Now I want to return a hash with only the unique hashes/offers. Also, I want `:price` hash to have the values averaged.

So, the final offers array will have:

```
offers=[offer1, offer2,...]
```

`offer1[:price]` will have values equal to average of the values of each key from duplicated offer hashes and same with `offer2[:price] and so on` so that in end I end with an hash with only unique offers.

offers1..6 can be duplicate with same id and price hash different. If they are duplicate we need to do the averaging otherwise not.

Is there an elegant way to do all of this?
I have tried grouping the hashes with a unique key and merging the price hashes of each. But am unable to reach the final solution.

my attempt:

```
    rooms_hash = rooms.map do |room|
      unless room[:offers].uniq.count == room[:offers].count
        grouped_offers = room[:offers].group_by{|x| x[:room_category_id]}
        offer_values = grouped_offers.values
        price_array = offer_values.map do |v| 
          v.inject do |k, v| 
            k.merge!(price: k[:price].merge(v[:price]){|_, a, b| [a, b].flatten })
          end
        end
        price_array.map do |o|
          o[:price] = {}.tap{ |h| o[:price].each {|k, list| h[k] = list.all?{|e| [Fixnum, NilClass].include? e.class} ? list.map(&:to_i).sum/list.size : list.compact.first ; h  } }
        end
        price_array
      end
    end
    rooms.zip(rooms_hash).map do |room,averaged_offers|
      if room[:offers].count > 1
        room[:offers] = averaged_offers.select{|offer| offer[:room_category_id] == room[:room_category_id]}
        room
      end
    end
```

This code actually fails when I don't get any duplicates. So how can I check for that as well?

Edit:

Yes offers is an array and offers1..6 are hashes.

offer1..._hash = `{:offer_id=>"uuid", :price=>{:amount=>4422380, :gross_amount=>4422380, :currency=>"INR", :tax=>434318, :hotel_fees=>0, :base_fare=>3988062}, .....}`

Comment: can you add samples of your hashes offer1 and offer2

Comment: Your offers 'hash' and final 'hash' look like arrays.

Comment: Further to @Mark's comment, `{offer1, offer2, offer3}` is not a valid Ruby object, as the elements of the hash are not key-value pairs.

Comment: Since you've tagged this Rails, I think you're not taking full advantage of your Models. You can avoid some of this data structure complexity and also neaten your code by moving Offer-related logic to a model.

Comment: @sa77 offer1..6 have same keys. And yes offers is an array. Can't use models here for this one.

Comment: I disagree. Offer is a concept that can easily be made into a class. A Rails model does not necessarily have to inherit from ActiveRecord.

Comment: I know. But I can't use it here. There are restrictions to the codebase.